# Trying to make a pre-commit hook that checks if files in index are formatted correctly

Tags: bash, git, grep, pre-commit-hook

I've been trying to make a pre-commit hook that checks if files in the index are formatted correctly. I've tried so many things already but I just can't get the grep to work correctly. This is my code right now:

```
for FILE in $(git diff --cached --name-only)
do
    if [[ "$FILE" =~ \.(c|h|cpp|cc)$ ]]; then
        exec C:/dev/uct/clang-format-15.0.3.exe --dry-run -Werror $FILE | grep -c "violations"
    fi
done
```

I expect it to print the number of files that have formatting issues (I actually want to search for the string -Wclang-format-violations but I simplified it for testing).

If I &> the clang-format output to a file the violations correctly printed to that file.

```
exec C:/dev/uct/clang-format-15.0.3.exe --dry-run -Werror $FILE &> temp.txt
```

If I then run grep from the command line on that file it works.

```
grep -c violations temp.txt
```

I also tried grep on the file from the script but for some reason that didn't produce any output either (though I would prefer to not have to create a file).

```
exec C:/dev/uct/clang-format-15.0.3.exe --dry-run -Werror $FILE &> temp.txt
grep -c violations temp.txt
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought I would get this to work in half an hour at most.

Comment: in one case you're doing `>&` (stdout and stderr) but in the other you're doing `|` (just stdout) -- did you mean `|&` ?

Comment: In the redirect to file case, you're using `&>` which redirects stderr. Do you want to use `|&` to pipe to grep?

Comment: Also, you're looking at the _files on disk_, not the _files in the index_. If somebody has staged changes but has still different changes in the working directory (perhaps from `git add -p`), your hook will ignore the staged changes.

Comment: Yes indeed, I needed to pipe the error stream. I'm not very experienced with Linux so was not aware that there was a difference.
@Edward: I'm under the impression that the files on disk will also contain the staged changes. True, I will also evaluate the unstaged changes but I'm willing to live with that for the sake of simplification. I will have to test this once my setup is a bit more mature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `grep` is that you're not redirecting `stderr`, only `stdout`. (In your redirection to a file, you *are* redirecting stderr as well, with `>&`.) To capture stderr in the pipe, use `|&`.

---

*However* you have a mismatch between what's staged to be committed and what you're looking at. In git, a *file* isn't staged to be committed, but its contents are. That means that you can stage - for example - part of a files contents to be committed. The file's contents in the working directory thus would not match what is staged.

Here's a concrete example:

```
echo "hello" > hello_world.txt
git add hello_world.txt
echo "world" >> hello_world.txt
```

At this point, the contents staged in the index (from the `git add` on line 2) are `hello`. But the file contains `hello world` on disk.

`git status` will show the file both as staged *and* modified:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   hello_world.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   hello_world.txt
```

If you were to run `git commit` now, only the `hello` would be committed, not the file as it exists on disk.

---

That means that you want to look at the *staged contents* of the file -- which is what will actually be committed -- not just the file on disk. Otherwise you may get false positives or negatives.

To handle this case, you can pass what's staged to `clang-format` using the `git show` command. (`git show :filename` will output the *staged* contents of `filename`.)

Try this:

```
for FILE in $(git diff --cached --name-only)
do
    if [[ "$FILE" =~ \.(c|h|cpp|cc)$ ]]; then
        git cat-file --filters ":${FILE}" | C:/dev/uct/clang-format-15.0.3.exe --dry-run -Werror --assume-filename="${FILE}" |& grep -c grep -c "\-Wclang\-format\-violations"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I was willing to live with the index vs disk discrepancies since my bash skills are clearly too rudimentary to fix it quickly. But since you're so kind to provide an example solution I tried it out. First there is a small typo in your suggestion (--assume=filename should be --assume-filename) but a bigger issue is that git diff uses LF line endings but -since I'm working on Windows- our clang-format config file demands CR LF line endings. I'm trying to see if I can find a fix for this but so far I've found nothing.

Comment: Ok, managed to fix the line endings issue by using unix2dos. The command works looking like this:
git show ":${FILE}" | unix2dos | "$CLANG_FORMAT" --dry-run -Werror --assume-filename="${FILE}" |& grep -c "\-Wclang\-format\-violations"
This, of course, sweeps any line-ending mistakes in the files under the rug.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the typo. I hadn't considered crlf filtering... Using `git cat-file` instead of `git show` may help? I updated my answer.